# MySQL update Column in increment base based on other column value

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table including following columns :

```
+------------+-------------+
|  auto_no   | auto_no_new |
+------------+-------------+
| 2021-10431 |       20577 |
| 2021-10432 |       20578 |
| 2021-10433 |       20579 |
| 2021-10434 |       20580 |
| 2021-10435 |       20581 |
| 2021-10436 |       20582 |
+------------+-------------+
```

Value in the "auto_no" column increments with relevant year. The values show in the table started previously and changed at the beginning of the year as above. Then I needs to start the values in the "auto_no" columns as follows :

```
+------------+-------------+
|  auto_no   | auto_no_new |
+------------+-------------+
| 2021-00001 |       20577 |
| 2021-00002 |       20578 |
| 2021-00003 |       20579 |
| 2021-00004 |       20580 |
| 2021-00005 |       20581 |
| 2021-00006 |       20582 |
+------------+-------------+
```

I used following query

```
update table set auto_no LIKE %'Y'- '????1'% where auto_no_new > 20577
```

But didn't get the desired output. What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: That looks pretty wrong - there's no `SET LIKE`. Why not generate such values through your application?

Comment: @  Nico Haase. Now it is sat as your suggestion. But previously added data records( Aprox : 550) should be changed using an update query. So, I requested that

Comment: That might be possible through some kind of function in MySQL, but according to my knowledge not in a single `UPDATE` query. I would not invest too much time in figuring that out - writing some code in your application might get you to the desired result much faster

Comment: 20577 - 20576 = ?

Comment: @ P.Salmon. No. The change should be applied from 20577 to upwards

Comment: See this example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e907d2886dc56bd28a46002d63a6f08

Comment: @fadlikidd. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by auto_no_new ASC),5,0)) new_no,
       auto_no,
       auto_no_new fr' at line 1

Comment: what mariadb version are you using?

Comment: @ fadlikidd . 5x. And want to update existing records (Within the auto_no) column reference to greater than 20576 in auto_no_new

Comment: Unfortunately [ROW_NUMBER()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/) function only available on MariaDB 10.2 and above but there might be another way. Let me try something and get back to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226966/discussion-between-mcit-trends-and-fadlikidd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems trivial

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(auto_no varchar(12), auto_no_new int);
insert into t values
( '2021-10431' ,       20577 ),
( '2021-10432' ,       20578 ),
( '2021-10433' ,       20579 ),
( '2021-10434' ,       20580 ),
( '2021-10435' ,       20581 ),
( '2021-10436' ,       20582 );

update t
        set auto_no = concat(substring_index(auto_no,'-',1),'-',lpad(auto_no_new - 20576,5,'0'))
where substring_index(auto_no,'-',1) = 2021;

select * from t;

+------------+-------------+
| auto_no    | auto_no_new |
+------------+-------------+
| 2021-00001 |       20577 |
| 2021-00002 |       20578 |
| 2021-00003 |       20579 |
| 2021-00004 |       20580 |
| 2021-00005 |       20581 |
| 2021-00006 |       20582 |
+------------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.013 sec)
```

or if you don't know the min(auto_no_new)

```
update t cross join(select min(auto_no_new) - 1 minno from t where substring_index(auto_no,'-',1)  = 2021) s 
        set auto_no = concat(substring_index(auto_no,'-',1),'-',lpad(auto_no_new - s.minno,5,'0'))
where substring_index(auto_no,'-',1) = 2021;
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing a few tests, this is what I come up with:

```
UPDATE table1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) R 
SET auto_no=CONCAT(SUBSTRING(auto_no,1,LOCATE('-',auto_no)),LPAD(@rn := @rn+1,5,0))
WHERE auto_no LIKE '2021-%';
```

However, I advise you to **please don't run the update query without backing up your table first.** I think the best way is for you to create a copy of the original table and run the update query over it rather than doing it on the original table. At least that would give you chance to do-over if something went wrong. Also, once you're satisfied with the end result (after the update), you can simply rename the original table to something like `table1_original` then rename the copy table as the original table.

[Here is a fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b4ff472ad1c04a136539eb59b81029ba)